# command substitution in RUBY

Tags: ruby

Please explain the Ruby code below, I can't able to understand the code.

In command_substitution.rb

```
a = %x!ps -def |grep bash!
puts a
```

Output

```
1000      3806  3799  0 10:54 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
1000      4981  4979  0 12:50 pts/0    00:00:00 sh -c ps -def |grep bash
1000      4984  4981  0 12:50 pts/0    00:00:00 grep bash
```

I searched to find out what is command substitution using Google. But, I didn't get the exact explanation about it.

Please explain .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%x` notation is a literal for executing a shell script. Here, the character `!` is used to indicate the start and the end of the literal. It runs the command `ps -def |grep bash` in the shell, assigns the result to variable `a`, and prints it.

Within the shell script, `ps` gets the running processes, `|` passes that to the next command, which is `grep`, which searches for the string `bash` within the processes shown.